# Why is this fragment's fields null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

In my parent Fragment's onCreateView method, I invoke the Child Fragment Manager to insert a Fragment into the layout. This child fragment contains a few FloatingActionButtons.

After I commit the transaction, I then check the contents of my underlying list (powering a RecyclerView), and based on whether any values are present, I either hide/unhide some of the FloatingActionButtons.

However it's telling me that the buttons are null! Does committing a Fragment transaction not call all of its typical lifecycle events first? Is there a way to force it to wait? Is there a better practice for this?

Comment: I believe you can also call `executePendingTransactions()` on the fragment manager and the fragment's `onCreateView()` will be called as part of that. Not saying this is the best way as warned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()) but it might be an option.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan It doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: This is really upsetting, it should not be this hard to do something so simple in Android

Comment: I never tried it using child fragments but it worked with fragments added in an activity for me. However, I am not sure if `onCreateView()` is guaranteed to be called as a part of that or if it just so happened to occur in my case, or if the fact you are trying to do it with a child fragment makes a difference. Anyways it seems you should have been able to modify Jeffrey Blattman's answer to fit your needs. If something didn't work you should probably add some code to your question on how you are currently trying to do this to make sure something else isn't wrong.

Comment: I don't see how that answer is relevant to what I'm trying to do. All I'm trying to do is modify the visibility of some buttons in the child fragment if a list in the parent fragment is empty/not empty. That's IT.

Comment: Yes but you said at the point in time you are trying to modify the visibility of the buttons they are null. By using a callback to the parent fragment as mentioned in the answer you will know that you can access the fragment's buttons and update their visibility accordingly without them being null. Depending on the order of things maybe you can even pass an argument to the child fragment to show/hide the buttons by default and avoid this altogether.

Comment: But then if I use a callback I have to somehow set the visibilities all the way from the Activity? I don't see how I can do this. In the Activity I only have the parent Fragment.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depending on what API you are targeting or if you are using the compatibility library you could either use `getParentFragment()` or `setTargetFragment()` combined with `getTargetFragment()` and use the parent fragment as the callback.

Comment: I don't see how that accomplishes what I am trying to do here. Again all I am trying to do is change the visibility of the child fragment's buttons.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Made a full / simple example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017131/how-do-i-dynamically-make-this-child-fragments-textview-null

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan `executePendingTransactions()` does not cause the entire fragment lifecycle to be executed synchronously.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman Yeah I noticed based on OP's comment. I wasn't positive on that and that is why I only mentioned it might be an option. I'm not sure under what circumstances it does and does not trigger `onCreateView()` to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit is not synchronous. There's no guarantee when the fragment's life cycle will execute.

If you need to know when the fragment is "ready", implement a callback from the fragment to the hosting activity letting it know.

```
class CustomB extends CustomA { 
  interface Listener {
    void onViewCreated();
  }

  public View onCreateView() {
     View v = super.onCreateView();

     if (getActivity() instanceof Listener) {
       ((Listener)getActivity()).onViewCreated();
     }

     return v;
  }
}
```

Generally speaking you should try to design your fragments to be self-contained. If the fragment is tightly bound to the activity, consider implementing the functionality as a custom `View` instead.

Comment: The fragment containing the FloatingActionButtons is used in several different places in the app which is why I made it a Fragment. Since it is bound to the Activity somewhat in this one case, I would Extend it instead?

Comment: If you can't modify the original fragment, yes, you can easily add the functionality I write above through extension.