# How do I dynamically make this child Fragment's TextView visible/invisible?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a main Activity containing a parent Fragment, which in turn contains a child Fragment. I am trying to make a TextView in the child Fragment visible/invisible dynamically.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This text belongs to the Activity"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_parent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This text belongs to the parent fragment"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This text belongs to the child fragment"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="But make this text visible dynamically!"
        android:id="@+id/make_this_text_visible"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String PARENT_TAG = "parent_tag";
    private ParentFragment mParentFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mParentFragment = ParentFragment.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.parent_container, mParentFragment, PARENT_TAG).commit();
        }
        else {
            mParentFragment = (ParentFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PARENT_TAG);
        }
    }
}
```

ParentFragment.java

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String CHILD_TAG = "child_tag";
    private ChildFragment mChildFragment;
    private List<Integer> mList;

    public static ParentFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        ParentFragment fragment = new ParentFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);
        mList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mChildFragment = ChildFragment.newInstance();
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.child_container, mChildFragment, CHILD_TAG).commit();
        }
        else {
            mChildFragment = (ChildFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CHILD_TAG);
        }
        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions(); //doesn't seem to do anything!
        doStuff();

        return view;
    }

    void doStuff() {
        mList.add(4); //pretend this is actually querying a database.
        //for simplicity it just receives a single 4.

        if (mList.size() > 0) { //the list is not empty, display the text!
            mChildFragment.setTextVisible(); //error! the textivew of the child fragment is null right now
        }
        else {
            mChildFragment.setTextInvisible(); //error! the textivew of the child fragment is null right now
        }
    }
}
```

ChildFragment.java

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView mTextView;

    public static ChildFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.make_this_text_visible);
        return view;
    }

    public void setTextVisible() {
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public void setTextInvisible() {
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that the child fragment is formed by the time I call doStuff() in the ParentFragment?

Comment: make an interface to perform callback, and implement it in child fragment and call it by parent

Comment: like public interface Foo{ public void onPerform(Textview v); }

Comment: below answer is like what i want to answer. Im on remote so cannot typying full code.. :( sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is keep the state of the text view visibility so it can be updated properly once the view has been created if it hasn't been already. Instead of separate methods for `setTextVisible()` and `setTextInvisible` have a single method `setTextVisibile(boolean isVisible)` and implement it as follows:

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private boolean mIsTextVisible;

    public static ChildFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ChildFragment fragment = new ChildFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.make_this_text_visible);
        setTextVisible(mIsTextVisible);

        return view;
    }

    public void setTextVisible(boolean isVisible) {
        mIsTextVisible = isVisible;
        if(mTextView != null) {
            mTextView.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the parent fragment you can call `doStuff()` without worrying about the current state of the views in the `ChildFragment` since `mIsTextVisible` is properly set. If the `mTextView` is null at the time `setTextVisible()` is called the visibility will still be properly set in `onCreateView()`.

Just take care to save and restore the `mIsTextVisible` flag when the fragment is recreated such as when the device is rotated.

---

### Alternative Answer Using A Callback

Using callbacks update the `ParentFragment` to implement
`ChildFragment.OnViewCreatedListener` and its method.

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment
    implements ChildFragment.OnViewCreatedListener {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated() {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

And then in `ChildFragment`

```
public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface OnViewCreatedListener {
        void onViewCreated();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.make_this_text_visible);

        if(getParentFragment() instanceof OnViewCreatedListener) {
            ((OnViewCreatedListener) getParentFragment()).onViewCreated();
        } else if (getActivity() instanceof OnViewCreatedListener) {
            ((OnViewCreatedListener) getActivity()).onViewCreated();
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without ChildFragment assuming that there is a parent fragment? i.e. it could be possible that MainActivity is the parent of ChildFragment, etc. In other words can it communicate back through to the Activity first and then communicate to ParentFragment?

Comment: Give me a minute because I'm also updating this with a solution I would use instead of the callback.

Comment: I also updated the answer to show how to make the callback approach work both with activities and fragments. Basically you just also see if the activity implements the callback interface too.

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer the first method over the callback approach?

Comment: That is more personal preference. The logic seems more straightforward to me not having to wait for the callback method to deal with the `Fragment`.

Comment: Does the callback method violate the principle of fragment-fragment communication at all? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: "Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly."

Comment: in other words is there an "accepted practice" approach that involves the Activity implementing the interface and then somehow interacting with ParentFragment to let it know the ChildFragment is ready?

Comment: It is of course best if you can avoid fragment to fragment communication but I think that last sentence saying fragments should never communicate is too strong. If that were the case they shouldn't have methods such as `getParentFragment` and `getTargetFragment`. Also, with this approach you aren't dependent on any single fragment implementation but rather an interface.

Comment: If I were to go through the Activity, then the Activity would implement the listener and then call mParentFragment.onChildViewCreated(), which would then call doStuff()?

Comment: I believe so which makes it much worse. I don't think you can get a fragment's child fragments from the host activity but I'll do a quick test and see.

Comment: Didn't see a way to get a child fragment from an activity without first getting the parent fragment.